# Python -- output repeated

Tags: python, parsing, split

##### File name is a text file. searching for an e-mail address after FROM

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

fh = open(fname)
count = 0

for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("From"):
        continue
    wds = line.split()
    print(wds[1])
    count +=1

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

#Output Sample#

```
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za

stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za 

louis@media.berkeley.edu

louis@media.berkeley.edu

zqian@umich.edu

zqian@umich.edu
```

I fixed the code with a workaround but just wanted to know why it doubled the output. Thanks

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your code will repeat output ih there are repetitive `From:` lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it's not an issue with the code. As a test, I made a txt doc and called upon that specific doc. It gave the correct output.

The text doc was:
From @ABCDEFG
From @checkA
From @checkB

@checkC

From @checkD

fname = "text.txt"

fh = open(fname)
count = 0

for line in fh:
line = line.rstrip()
if not line.startswith("From"):
continue
wds = line.split()
print(wds[1])
count +=1

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).